# C printf prints two elements from array when it only should print one

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to programming and have a little problem...

My output when running the code is a bit wrong, there should only be Wednesday on line 3 in the output. What causes this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    enum weekdays {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};
    enum weekdays current_day;

    float highest_temperature = 0;
    float average_temperature = 0;
    float current_temperature = 0;

    char show_weekdays[7][9] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    for(current_day = Monday; current_day <= Sunday; current_day++){

        printf("Enter temperature for %s (in Celsius): ", show_weekdays[current_day]);
        scanf("%f", &current_temperature);

        average_temperature += current_temperature;

        if(current_temperature > highest_temperature){

            highest_temperature = current_temperature;

        }

    }

    average_temperature /= 7;

    printf("The average temperature was: %.2f Celsius\n", average_temperature);
    printf("The highest temperature was: %.2f Celsius\n", highest_temperature);

}
```

Output:

```
Enter temperature for Monday (in Celsius): 1
Enter temperature for Tuesday (in Celsius): 2
Enter temperature for WednesdayThursday (in Celsius): 3
Enter temperature for Thursday (in Celsius): 4
Enter temperature for Friday (in Celsius): 5
Enter temperature for Saturday (in Celsius): 6
Enter temperature for Sunday (in Celsius): 7
The average temperature was: 4.00 Celsius
The highest temperature was: 7.00 Celsius
```

Comment: Both answers have been downvoted. I'm guessing (with no real evidence) that it was done by the same person Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. This is not a simple typographical error, it appears to be a misunderstanding about how strings work in C.

Comment: I am upvoting the question because it was well presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string `"Wednesday"` requires 10 characters, not 9. A string is terminated by, and includes, a closing null character `'\0'`.

The declaration as you have it isn't illegal (which is why you didn't get a compile-time warning or error message). As a special case, C lets you use a string literal to initialize an array of the exact length of the literal (the length is 1 less than the size). The terminating `'\0'` won't be stored. That's fine if you don't depend on the content being a valid string, but you do. (Strictly speaking your program's behavior is undefined, but that's a subtle point that we needn't get into.)

A better way to define `show_weekdays` is as an array of pointers, each of which points to a string:

```
const char *const show_weekdays[] = {
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
};
```

(When I say "better", I mean it's less error-prone and easier to maintain. There might be some cost in extra storage to hold the pointers, but it's trivial for something this size.)

Computers are *really* good at counting things. Let them do it for you whenever possible.

The two `const`s ensure that you won't accidentally try to modify either the pointers or the strings they point to.

Comment: Strictly speaking I don't think it has UB, because the pointer `show_weekdays[2]` decays to is also a pointer into the representation array of the whole 2d array.

Comment: @R..: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) Annex J lists circumstances that cause undefined behavior. One of them is: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration int
`a[4][5]`) (6.5.6)." A 2d array is an array of arrays. It's not a long array of the element type. (But the fact that the element type here is `char` might invoke some special-case rules.)

Comment: Note that on a 64-bit machine, the array of pointers occupies 56 bytes and the strings occupy just under 70 bytes, vs the 2D array only needing 70 bytes.  It isn’t immediately clear that the pointers are better; even in a 32-bit machine, the array of pointers requires more storage.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Depends on what you mean by "better". I'll gladly pay a few extra bytes for better clarity and maintainability.

Answer (score 4):

The array length is too short, "Wednesday" has 9 letters and needs a nul string terminator.

```
char show_weekdays[7][9];
```

should be

```
char show_weekdays[7][10];
```

The C compiler only includes that string terminator **if there is room for it in the array**. The compiler only complains when there is not enough room for the data.

Comment: The Grinch must have been browsing this question spreading DVs.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the one by Keith is much better, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I already acknowledged that, which you would have seen if you read the comments. This answer was converted from a comment that had several ticks. After that, the better answer came, and was improved. I wasn't prepared to have a race. You didn't downvote, thank you, but your comment was an unnecessary put-down. Have a nice Christmas.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the comment chain since deleted by various parties. You missed it.